# pfproj - unknown File extension (how open it)

Tags: visual-studio

can anyone help me? How i can open and edit these files?. I do not know, how can i open file with extension *.pfproj (it looks like Visual Studio project, but it is not). Thanks for advices
[image: Filelist]

Comment: It could be PowerShell Studio 2015

Comment: Yes, it is PowerShell Studio. Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It is for PowerShell Studio